# BeautifulSoup and CSV files

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to pull the table from http://www.atpworldtour.com/Rankings/Top-Matchfacts.aspx?y=2015&s=1# and put all the information in a csv file.

I've done this but am having a few issues. The first column of the table contains both the ranking of the player and their name. I want to split these up so that one column just contains the ranking and the other column contains the player name.

Here's the code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

URL = 'http://www.atpworldtour.com/Rankings/Top-Matchfacts.aspx?y=2015&s=1#'
req = urllib2.Request(URL)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
tables = soup.findAll('table')
my_table = tables[0]

with open('out2.csv', 'w') as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
    for row in my_table.findAll('tr'):
        cells = [c.text.encode('utf-8') for c in row.findAll('td')]
        if len(cells) == 16: 
            csvwriter.writerow(cells)
```

Here's the output of a few players:

```
"1
                            Novak Djokovic",SRB,5-0,0-0,9,1.8,7,1.4,62%,74%,58%,88%,42%,68%,39%-57%,46%
"2
                            Roger Federer",SUI,1-1,0-1,9,4.5,2,1.0,59%,68%,54%,84%,46%,67%,37%-49%,33%
"3
                            Andy Murray",GBR,0-0,0-0,0,0.0,0,0.0,0%,0%,0%,0%,0%,0%,0%-0%,0%
"4
                            Rafael Nadal",ESP,11-3,2-1,25,1.8,18,1.3,68%,69%,57%,82%,43%,57%,36%-58%,38%
"5
                            Kei Nishikori",JPN,5-0,0-0,14,2.8,9,1.8,57%,75%,62%,92%,49%,80%,39%-62%,42%
```

As you can see the first column isn't displayed properly with the number being on a higher line than the rest of the data as well as the extremely large gap.

The HTML code for the problem column is slightly more complex than the rest of the columns:

```
<td class="col1" rel="1">1
                            <a href="/Tennis/Players/Top-Players/Novak-Djokovic.aspx">Novak Djokovic</a></td>
```

I tried separating it from that but I couldn't get it to work and thought it might be easier to fix the current CSV file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separating the field after pulling it out is pretty easy. You've got a number, a bunch of whitespace, and a name. So just use `split`, with the default delimiter, and a max split of 1:

```
cells = [c.text.encode('utf-8') for c in row.findAll('td')]
if len(cells) == 16:
    cells[0:1] = cells[0].split(None, 1)
    csvwriter.writerow(cells)
```

---

But you can also separate it from within the soup, and that's probably more robust:

```
cells = row.find_all('td')
cell0 = cells.pop(0)
rank = next(cell0.children).strip().encode('utf-8')
name = cell0.find('a').text.encode('utf-8')
cells = [rank, name] + [c.text.encode('utf-8') for c in cells]
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the value you're concerned with contains multiple tabs and the player's name is directly after the final tab, I'd suggest split by tab and collect the last item from the resulting tuple.

The line I added is `cells[0] = cells[0].split('\t')[-1]`

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

URL = 'http://www.atpworldtour.com/Rankings/Top-Matchfacts.aspx?y=2015&s=1#'
req = urllib2.Request(URL)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
tables = soup.findAll('table')
my_table = tables[0]

with open('out2.csv', 'w') as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
    for row in my_table.findAll('tr'):
        cells = [c.text.encode('utf-8') for c in row.findAll('td')]
        if len(cells) == 16: 
            cells[0] = cells[0].split('\t')[-1]
            csvwriter.writerow(cells)

f.close()
```

Comment: why does this get a downgrade?  Does this fail for anybody?  Does it not obtain the goal?

Comment: I guess we have a coder out there who thinks there's only one way to do something.